# How to access Page's Tabs with facebooker2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tabs, facebooker2

Does anyone know how to get list of Page's Tabs with facebooker2 please?

Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty straight fwd to do with https://github.com/arsduo/koala

assuming you have the access token for the user, you can get all its pages / apps by getting the accounts connection:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(access_token)
pages = graph.get_connections("me", "accounts")
```

from there, you need to get the correct access token for the page, and then get the tabs using the tabs connection.